# How to call a async method repeatedly until you get success in native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have an async method which returns either success or fail. I have to keep calling this async method from another method until I get success. But if it fails repeatedly for 5 times then I have to stop calling it.

```
let count = 0;

function myAsyncApi(url){
  
   //this is a fake async method which return success at certain point of time
  
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(count === 5){
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve('succes')
        }, 100);
      }
      else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            reject('failure');
        }, 100);          
      }
      
      count++;
  });
}

function retry(){
  // I have to call myAsyncApi('/url') from this function repeatedly
  // Whenever we get success from myAsyncApi(url) we have to stop calling the API
  // if we get fail then call myAsyncApi('/url') again until count reaches 5

 // how can we achieve this without using async/await in this function


}
```

Comment: You can avoid using async/await, but you can't avoid that workflow being asynchronous. What do you mean by that last comment? If you just want to avoid async/await, use `promise.then()` and `promise.catch()` and return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrying should be pretty easy with a little recursion. Basically if the request succeeds, just return. If it fails, otherwise catch the error and try again with 1 less attempt remaining.

```
function fetchAndRetry(retryAttempts = 5) {
  if (retryAttempts < 0) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error("Exceeded maximum retries fetching /url"));
  }
  console.log("Attempting, " + retryAttempts + " attempts left.");
  return myAsyncApi('/url').catch(() => fetchAndRetry(retryAttempts - 1));
}

fetchAndRetry().then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped

Answer (score 2):

```
function retry(retries = 5) {
   if (retries < 0) return
   myAsyncApi('/url')
       .then(res => console.log(res))
       .catch(res => retry(retries - 1))
}
```

you can call retry with `setTimeout` if you want some delay between calls