# Repeat async function until true

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I have an `async` function that checks for the status of an order (`checkOrderStatus()`). I would like to repeat this function until it returns either `"FILLED"` or `"CANCELED"`, then use this return value in another function to decide to continue or stop the code. Every order goes through different status before being `"FILLED"` or `"CANCELED"`, therefore the need to repeat the `checkOrderStatus()` function (it is an API call).

What I have now is this, to repeat the `checkOrderStatus()` function:

```js
const watch = filter => {
    return new Promise(callback => {
        const interval = setInterval(async () => {
            if (!(await filter())) return;
            clearInterval(interval);
            callback();
        }, 1000);
    });
};

const watchFill = (asset, orderId) => {
    return watch(async () => {
        const { status } = await checkOrderStatus(asset, orderId);

        console.log(`Order status: ${status}`);

        if (status === 'CANCELED') return false;
        return status === 'FILLED';
    });
};
```

I then call `watchFill()` from another function, where I would like to check its return value (`true` or `false`) and continue the code if `true` or stop it if `false`:

```js
const sellOrder = async (asset, orderId) => {
    try {
        const orderIsFilled = await watchFill(asset, orderId);
        
        if (orderIsFilled) {
            //… Continue the code (status === 'FILLED'), calling other async functions …
        }
        else {
            //… Stop the code
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error('Err sellIfFilled() :', err);
    }
};
```

However, this does not work. I can see the status being updated in the terminal via the `console.log` in `watchFill()`, but it never stops and most importantly, the value in the `orderIsFilled` variable in `sellOrder()` does not get updated, whatever the value returned by `watchFill()` becomes.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a async method repeatedly until you get success in native javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098954/how-to-call-a-async-method-repeatedly-until-you-get-success-in-native-javascript)

Comment: @ggorlen Thank yes reopened

Comment: @AjayChambers That question has no delay/wait as this post does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`watch` never calls `resolve` (in the original code, this is misleadingly named `callback()`) with any value, so there's no way `const orderIsFilled = await watchFill(asset, orderId);` will populate `orderIsFilled` with anything but `undefined`.

If you save the result of `await filter()` in a variable and pass it to
`callback` as `callback(result)`, your code seems like it should work.

That said, the code can be simplified by using a loop and writing a simple `wait` function. This way, you can return a value (more natural than figuring out how/when to call `resolve`), keep the `new Promise` pattern away from the logic and avoid dealing with `setInterval` and the bookkeeping that goes with that.

```js
const wait = ms =>
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
;

const watch = async (predicate, ms) => {
  for (;; await wait(ms)) {
    const result = await predicate();
    
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
  }
};

/* mock the API for demonstration purposes */
const checkOrderStatus = (() => {
  let calls = 0;
  return async () => ({
    status: ++calls === 3 ? "FILLED" : false
  });
})();

const watchFill = (asset, orderId) =>
  watch(async () => {
    const {status} = await checkOrderStatus();
    console.log(`Order status: ${status}`);
    return status === "CANCELLED" ? false : status === "FILLED";
  }, 1000)
;

const sellOrder = async () => {
  try {
    const orderIsFilled = await watchFill();
    console.log("orderIsFilled:", orderIsFilled);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error('Err sellIfFilled() :', err);
  }
};
sellOrder();
```

Comment: I don't understand why I would need to check for `calls` and iterate over it in `checkOrderStatus`, as it is an API call ? Can't I just make the API call and do `if (status === 'FILLED') return true; else if (status === 'CANCELED') return false;` ?

Comment: No, I'm just mocking that function so you can run the example. The `if (status...` code you mention is still here, I just made it a ternary because I prefer ternaries. As I mentioned in the post, if you just save `await filled()` in a variable and pass that to `callback` you should be good to go. The snippet is just a cleanup job and proof-of-functionality.

Comment: I tried your solution using my API call in `checkOrderStatus` but I doesn't work. Is it worth noting that my `checkOrderStatus` is `async` and returns a `Promise` ?

Comment: What doesn't work about it, specifically? My `checkOrderStatus` is async as you can see. If you're struggling to make the existing answers work ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837554/6243352) is basically the same as mine), maybe the code you've shown us isn't enough of a [mcve] to illustrate what's really going on in your original program.

Answer (score 1):

The `watch` function clears the interval timer after the first call if `filter` resolves with `false`. `setInterval` doesn't wait for an async function to finish executing either so you'll have to create a loop yourself. Try this:

```js
const delay = milliseconds => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));

const watch = async check => {
    while (true) {
        if (await check()) {
            return;
        }

        await delay(1000);
    }
};
```

Because `watch` only resolves when `check` succeeds, it is not possible to fail so you don't need to check for it (this might be a bug in your code):

```js
const sellOrder = async (asset, orderId) => {
    try {
        await watchFill(asset, orderId);
        
        //… Continue the code (status === 'FILLED'), calling other async functions …
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error('Err sellIfFilled() :', err);
    }
};
```

[`p-wait-for`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-wait-for) contains an excellent implementation of this. You can use it like so:

```js
import pWaitFor from 'p-wait-for';

const watchFill = (asset, orderId) => pWaitFor(async () => {
    const { status } = await checkOrderStatus(asset, orderId);

    console.log(`Order status: ${status}`);

    if (status === 'CANCELED') return false;
    return status === 'FILLED';
}, {
    interval: 1000,
    leadingCheck: false
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I will give it a try. However, do you have any idea how to implement this in vanilla JS ? Thanks

Comment: Is the `check()` callback supposed to be my `checkOrderStatus` function ? If so, is the usage like so : `while (true) { if (await check() === 'FILLED') return true;  else if (await check() === 'CANCELED') return false; }` ?

Comment: The usage of the `watch` function is not changed, just the name of the variable. This means your current code that calls the `watch` function now works.

Comment: So I would use `watchFill` as it is right now but just change `watch` to the exemple you showed ?

Comment: Yup. Just remove your current `watch` function and replace it with the `watch` function I provided along with the `delay` function before it.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. I did just as you said, I can see in `console.log` the updated status, but `orderIsFilled` in `sellOrder()` is still undefined. Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Right now, `watchFill` should only be able to return `true`. Therefore, `if (orderIsFilled)` is redundant so after `const orderIsFilled = await watchFill(asset, orderId);` you should just assume that the operation succeeded. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive functionality like this:

```
const checkOrderStatus = async () => {
    // ... function does some work ...
    await someOtherFunction() // you can use here the other async function as well
    // ... function does some more work after returning from await ...
    if(/* if status is FILLED or CANCELED */) {
        // return true or false or some info about response for your needs
    } else {
        checkOrderStatus();
    }
}

// this will response back when status will be FILLED or CANCELED
await checkOrderStatus();
```

Comment: Shouldn't I use `await` before `checkOrderStatus()` in the `else` ?

Comment: No you don't need that. Note: since the call stack is empty after await, this means the call stack doesn’t grow with each recursive call. Therefore your call-stack never hits a size limit and the recursion continues as long as it can.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the function as you wrote it, with `if (status === 'FILLED') return true;  else if (status === 'CANCELED') return false;  else { checkOrderStatus() }`, but when I try to do `const orderIsFilled = await checkOrderStatus(asset, orderId)` in my other function, `orderIsFilled` contains undefined, therefore returning false (the `else` in `sellOrder()`), but I can see in a `console.log` in `checkOrderStatus` that the status has been filled. Any idea why ?

Comment: Without a delay, this doesn't preserve OP's intent. Seems like a lot is left to the imagination.